# Error updating table in SQL Server: Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

In C#, I want to write an update query with `smalldatetime` columns, I have seen several posts on Stackoverflow but I didn't find one to solve the error:

> Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.

I have a table `RESERVAS`, with 3 columns `ID_RESERVA` (`int`), `LLEGADA` (`smalldatetime`), `SALIDA` (`smalldatetime`)

The code:

```
 string strQuery = "UPDATE " + DB_TABLENAME + "  SET " +
 "LLEGADA = CONVERT(smalldatetime, '@LLEGADA', 126), " +
 "SALIDA = CONVERT(smalldatetime, '@SALIDA', 126) " +
 "WHERE ID_RESERVA = @ID_RESERVA";

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con); // con = SqlConnection
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID_RESERVA", SqlDbType.Int);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@LLEGADA", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@SALIDA", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime);

 cmd.Parameters["@ID_RESERVA"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(stringWithIdReserva);
 cmd.Parameters["@LLEGADA"].Value = stringWithLLegada.Replace(" ", "T"); //Real string value: "2015-03-30 00:00:00"
 cmd.Parameters["@SALIDA"].Value = stringWithSalida.InnerText.Replace(" ", "T"); //Real string value: "2015-04-01 00:00:00"

  try
  {
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  catch (SqlException ex)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you have wrapped your parameters with single tick marks. The way you have it coded it is trying to parse the string literals instead of the values in your parameters.

```
string strQuery = "UPDATE " + DB_TABLENAME + "  SET " +
 "LLEGADA = CONVERT(smalldatetime, @LLEGADA, 126), " +
 "SALIDA = CONVERT(smalldatetime, @SALIDA, 126) " +
 "WHERE ID_RESERVA = @ID_RESERVA";

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con); // con = SqlConnection
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID_RESERVA", SqlDbType.Int);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@LLEGADA", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@SALIDA", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime);

 cmd.Parameters["@ID_RESERVA"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(stringWithIdReserva);
 cmd.Parameters["@LLEGADA"].Value = stringWithLLegada.Replace(" ", "T"); //Real string value: "2015-03-30 00:00:00"
 cmd.Parameters["@SALIDA"].Value = stringWithSalida.InnerText.Replace(" ", "T"); //Real string value: "2015-04-01 00:00:00"

  try
  {
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  catch (SqlException ex)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  }
```

Comment: That's the one :). *Single tick marks*, I like it! A better name than apostrophes ;)

Comment: Single quotes yeah, much better. That's a better term of reference for us developers.

Comment: So, Have I to remove single tick marks in all types parameters or only dates and numerics?

Comment: Yes. If you have single quotes like in your original post it is NOT using the parameter there, it is using the string literal. Just like in every other place in t-sql a string is wrapped with single quotes.